# I have 1 TB disk but I'm only seeing 747 GB. How to recover the 253 GB missing?

Tags: disk-utility, disk-space, diskutil

I am not sure how to solve this.
I used to have macOS Monterey on my iMac late 2015 and it was running a bit slow. So I removed it, formatted the drive and did a fresh install of macOS Mojave, which makes it run smooth.

However, the drive is not showing 1 TB in Disk Utility nor Terminal's diskutil list, just the partition with the 743 GB. I am not sure how to regain the missing space.

This is what I see:

[image: diskutil list]

[image: Disk Utility]

As you can see, disk0 shows 1 TB.
Anyone knows how to get the full 1 TB back without having to go through the formatting/installation process again?

Thank you very much in advance!

**UPDATE:** Adding extra info as requested by David Anderson and Ezekiel:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Click the Partition button while on the same screen shown in your second screenshot and attach what it shows here please

Comment: Edit your question and add the output from the following commands. The output will show where the missing free space resides. `diskutil info disk0s1 | grep -e Size -e Offset` and `diskutil info disk0s2 | grep -e Size -e Offset`

Comment: Hello @Ezekiel and David Anderson, thank you for your answers. I have updated the ticket with the new images.

Comment: Hello @DavidAnderson, I'm assuming that this is the lost space, correct?

Partition Offset:          252897992704 Bytes (493941392 512-Byte-Device-Blocks)

Comment: Please don't post images of text from command output, as it's not searchable for others with similar issues. That may not strictly apply to your specific disk, but it is a good rule to follow when posting textual data. Enclose it in 
`backticks`

Comment: Thank you very much Andy, I didn't think of it. Will do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you already discovered, the missing space is between `disk0s1` and `disk0s2`. There is no simple method of adding this free space to your fresh install of Mojave. The easiest method would be to do another new fresh install where you erase the entire drive before installing Mojave. Below are the basic steps to install Mojave by use of a USB flash drive.

1. [Download Mojave from the Apps Store](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT211683).
2. Install the downloaded file to create the install application.
3. [Use the application to create a USB flash drive installer.](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201372)
4. Boot from the flash drive. (Hold down the option key at startup)
5. Erase the entire drive using the APFS format.
6. Install macOS to the new APFS volume.

Any Mac where the version of macOS requires the use of APFS will perform poorly, if installed entirely on a HDD. In other words, not installed on a SSD or Fusion drive. I have an iMac (21.5-inch, Late 2013) with a 1 GB SATA HDD. I encountered a significant increase in performance by installing macOS on an external USB SSD. I would probably get even better performance by replacing the internal SATA HDD with a internal SATA SSD. However, I did not wish to go through the trouble of dismantling the Mac. Currently, you can get a [500 GB Samsung T7 SSD for 105 CAD with free shipping](https://www.amazon.ca/Samsung-T7-Portable-SSD-MU-PC1T0T/dp/B0874YS2N7/ref=sr_1_1?crid=Z2P3QR102GDC&keywords=samsung%2Bt7&qid=1671565521&sprefix=samsung%2Bt7%2Caps%2C101&sr=8-1&th=1).

Comment: Hey Andy, thank you very much for the detailed answer. I guess I have no choice other than doing a fresh install following those steps. Thank you for your time!